# Is there any possibility to load a SQL file with inserts after(!) initialization?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My issue is, I want to initialize different Data for certain scenarios if I send a Request.

But not on the initialisation of the Database.

Is there any way on how to load an additional "data.sql" after the initialization and startup of the Spring Boot application?

Comment: Not exactly using the equivalent of data.sql. I think once the application is up and running then you need to insert data fundamentally using jdbc (though probably by passing SQL to a jdbcTemplate or using a framework such as a JPA implementation (Hibernate) or possibly MyBatis would be the closest to a data.sql type approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator` to populate a database using SQL scripts defined in external resource(s).

Sample usage:

```java
ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));

DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, dataSource);
```

You can put this into your controller handler method.